# How do I detect the case when my Azure role is moved to on a new VM?

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

Azure can sometimes restart the VM where my role instance is running and sometimes it can stop it on one VM and then deploy it onto another VM - for example if the hardware where the VM was running happens to break.

Clearly in both cases the VM uptime will reset.

How do I detect the latter - how do I tell that it's a new VM, not an old one after some automatic cleanup?

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: @GerrieSchenck: I need as much details as possible for debugging.

Comment: What exactly are you debugging? I can't imagine any reason to need this information.

Comment: @Jaxidian: I come to office on Monday, grab the logs and realize that all instances were restarted on Saturday. I'd like to know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would work, but perhaps you could create a Local Storage drive with "Clean on Role Recycle" set to false. When your role starts, check for existence of a predetermined file. If the file is there, then you're restarting on an old VM. If there is no file, you're starting on a new VM. In either case, write the file after you check for it.

Comment: I am using this solution. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% fool proof method but what you could do is when a VM starts up you can get the id of your role instance using [`RoleInstance.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstance.id.aspx) property and the computer name of the VM using [`Environment.MachineName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.environment.machinename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and save it somewhere in table storage. Then every time a VM starts you could check against this table to identify if a new VM has been allocated to your role instance.

Comment: If my instance is moved to another VM its `RoleInstance.Id` will surely not change. Can I be sure that the VM computer name is not reused for the new VM?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if the same computer name can't be used again. That's why I said it's not 100% fool proof. Just thinking out loud -- you could have a table with PartitionKey = RoleInstance.Id and RowKey = Computer Name (or vice versa) and then add some additional parameters (not sure what they would be) to help you identify this uniquely and granularly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you trap & log (to shared storage like ATS/blob/SQLAzure) all of the RoleEnvironment events, such as Stopping/Starting/etc along with the machine name and instance Id.  This will get you all of the information necessary to debug when your machines are restarted and whether they're moved.

Comment: I already do that, but that won't help if a machine name is reused for a new VM.

Comment: It will not.  Perhaps, please a file somewhere on a local hard-drive first time when your app starts up with a timestamp and other relevant information?  Then, upon subsequent times during app's startup, check if the file is there first and if not add it only.  This way, if the machine is re-imaged and the file is gone, you'll know that it is what has happened.